# Functional equation involving $f(x^4)+f(x^2)+f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> Find all increasing functions $f$ from positive reals to positive reals satisfying $f(x^4) + f(x^2) + f(x) = x^4 + x^2 + x$.

It's easy to show that $f(1)=1$, and I was also able to show that
$$f(x)-x = f(x^{(8^k)}) - x^{(8^k)}$$
for all integers $k$.

But where to go from here? Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's clear that $f(x)=x$ satisfies the equation, but I'm not sure that's the only one.

Comment: Just a thought: If you set $g(x):=f(x)-x$ then the equation above becomes $g(x^4)+g(x^2)+g(x)=0$. However, now it's harder to take into account the fact that $f$ is increasing.

Comment: @Cesareo, Is it increasing or $(0,\infty)$-valued over $(0,\infty)$ for any non-trivial choices of $C_1'$ and $C_2'$?

Comment: @SangchulLee You got it!. I simply assumed a real function. I  didn't see the increasing. My fault.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(x) = f(x)-x$. We obtain $g(x^4)+g(x^2)+g(x)=0$. Define $a_n = g(x^{2^n})$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z$ where $x\ne 1,x>0$. It follows that
$$
a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_n=0,
$$ and from this 2nd order linear equation we get for some $A,B$,$$
a_n =\begin{cases}A,\quad n\equiv 0 \;\text{(mod }3)\\ B,\quad n\equiv 1 \;\text{(mod }3)\\-A-B,\quad n\equiv 2 \;\text{(mod }3)\end{cases}.
$$

It says that $(a_n)$ is a $3$-periodic sequence. Now we claim that $a_n = 0$ for every $n$. Since $f(x)=x+g(x)$ is increasing, it holds for each $k=0,1,2$ and all $n\equiv k\text{ (mod} \;3)$, $x>1$ that 
$$
x^{2^n}+a_k \le x^{2^{n+1}}+a_{k+1}\le x^{2^{n+2}}+a_{k+2}.
$$ Let $n\equiv k\text{ (mod} \;3)$ tend to $-\infty$ to obtain
$$
a_k\le a_{k+1}\le a_{k+2}
$$ for each $k=0,1,2$. This implies $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$ and thus $a_n = 0,\ \forall n$ follows for $x>1$. The case where $0<x<1$ can be treated similarly by noting that
$$
x^{2^n}+a_k \ge x^{2^{n+1}}+a_{k+1}\ge x^{2^{n+2}}+a_{k+2}.
$$
This proves $f(x)=x+g(x)=x$ for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 3):

First we show that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(1) = 1$. Note that the limit of an increasing function from below or from above always exists. Let the limit from below be $a$ and the limit from above be $b$. If we take the limit from below of $f(x) + f(x^2) + f(x^4) = x + x^2 + x^4$, we get $a + a + a = 3$, so $a = 1$ (since as $x$ approaches $1$, $x^2$ and $x^4$ also approach $1$). Similarly from above, $b + b + b = 3$, so $b = 1$. Finally, we already know $f(1) = 1$. So
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(1) = 1.
$$

(In fact, we could show $f$ is continuous for all $x$, using a similar argument.)

To finish, consider your equation $f(x) + f(x^{8^k}) = x + x^{8^{k}}$. Take the limit as $k \to -\infty$. Regardless of $x$, $x^{8^k}$ approaches $x^{0} = 1$. So, we get
\begin{align*}
f(x) + 1 = x + 1 \\
\implies & \boxed{f(x) = x},
\end{align*}
which holds for all $x$. So $f(x) = x$ is the only solution.

Comment: Did you mean $x^4$, not $x^3$?

Comment: A minor error: $\lim\limits_{k\to-\infty} x^{8^k}=1$.

Comment: @Prasiortle Thanks, fixed

Comment: @Song Thanks for the correction. So I needed to do the limit at $x = 1$, not $x = 0$. Fixed now.

Comment: @Song Very nice solution by the way :)

Comment: @6005 Thank you for kind words. I like your $\lim_{x\to 1^\pm}f(x) =1$ trick, too :D

Comment: The solution $f(x)=x$ is a particular solution. The full solution is $$
f(x) = C'_1\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\log_2(\ln x)\right)+C'_2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\log_2(\ln x)\right)+x
$$

Comment: You define the limit from below of $f(x)$ to be $a$, but how do you show rigorously that e.g. the limit from below of $f(x^2)$ is also $a$?

Comment: Neat solution! (+1)

Comment: @Prasiortle (oops, restating the answer more clearly) That's a good question. So, if $a$ is the limit from below of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $1$, then note that as $x$ approaches $1$ from below, $x^2$ also approaches $1$ from below. It follows that the limit of $f(x^2)$ from below is also $a$.

Answer (score 0):

**If** we are interested in functions smooth enough to admit some power series expansion (around $x=0$):

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k$$

Since $$f(x^n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^{kn}$$
It will force relations between the coefficients in a systematic way which you can then investigate.

Comment: Doing this we immediately derive $f(x) = x$ since all other coefficients must be $0$. But how does it help? Most functions cannot be given as a power series.

Comment: @6005 : Yes the assumption here is if the function is smooth enough to admit a power series around $x = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $f(x)$ as a real function, calling $g(x) = f(x)-x$ we have

$$
g(x^4)+g(x^2)+g(x) = 0
$$

now calling $e^y = x$ we have

$$
g(e^{4y})+g(e^{2y})+g(e^y) = 0
$$

or

$$
G(4y)+G(2y)+G(y) = 0
$$

This recurrence equation has as solution

$$
G(y) = C_1 y^{-\frac{2 i \pi }{3 \ln 2}}+C_2 y^{\frac{2 i \pi }{3 \ln 2}}
$$

because

$$
\mathcal{G}(\log_2 (4y))+\mathcal{G}(\log_2(2y))+\mathcal{G}(\log_2 y)=0\\
\mathcal{G}(\log_2 y+2)+\mathcal{G}(\log_2 y +1)+\mathcal{G}(\log_2 y)=0
$$

and making $z = \log_2 y$ we get

$$
\mathcal{G}(z+2)+\mathcal{G}(z+1)+\mathcal{G}(z)=0
$$

which can be characterized as second order linear difference equation.

Then follows

$$
G(y) = C'_1 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{3}  \log_2 y\right)+C'_2\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{3}  \log_2 y\right) = g(e^y) = f(e^y)-e^y
$$

and finally

$$
f(x) = C'_1\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\log_2(\ln x)\right)+C'_2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\log_2(\ln x)\right)+x
$$

In case of $f(x)$ increasing then the solution is $f(x) = x$ with $C'_1=C'_2=0$

NOTE

Use this MATHEMATICA script to verify the recurrence equation as well as the final solution.

```
Clear[G]
G[y_] := Cos[(2 \[Pi] Log[2, y])/3] c1 + Sin[(2 \[Pi] Log[2, y])/3 ] c2
G[4 y] + G[2 y] + G[y] // FullSimplify

f[x_] := Cos[(2 \[Pi] Log[2, Log[x]])/3] c1 + Sin[(2 \[Pi] Log[2, Log[x]])/3 ] c2 + x
Assuming[x > 0, f[x^4] + f[x^2] + f[x] - x^4 - x^2 - x // FullSimplify]
```

Comment: I don't understand your solution. $C_1$ and $C_2$ differ depending on which $y$ you pick.

Comment: @6005 Did you check if $G(y)$ verify the recurrence equation $G(4y)+G(2y)+G(y)=0$ ?

Comment: what do you mean? I agree it verifies that recurrence, but the $C_1$ and $C_2$ are different depending on which $y$ you pick. There is actually an infinite-dimensional family of solutions.

Comment: @6005 A recursive equation is quite similar to a differential equation. This is a second order linear recursive equation so we have two free constant which can be determined depending on boundary conditions. So the solution is complete with two  arbitrary constant.

Comment: Unfortunately you are mistaken, it doesn't cover all solutions. For example: set $G(y) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi \log_2 y}{3} \right)$ if $y$ is a perfect power of $2$, otherwise set $G(y) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi \log_2 y}{3}\right)$. This is not covered by any pair $C_1'$, $C_2'$.

Comment: In general, we may pick for each $y \in [1,2)$ a different pair of constants $C_1'$ and $C_2'$. That's infinitely many constants. Then, $G(2y)$, $G(4y)$, $G(8y)$ and so on are determined by the constants $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ for that particular $y \in [1,2)$.

Comment: @6005 Did you REALLY did the substitution?  The recurrence equation is observed for any $C'_1,C'_2$ I included as a note this verification in a MATHEMATICA script.

Comment: I think 6005's point is fair. From $G(4y)+G(2y)+G(y)=0$ we do get information about the values $G(2^ky)$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$, but we cannot get anything about the value, say $G(3y/2)$. $G(y)$ and $G(3y/2)$ can be chosen independently.

Comment: @Song My solution is for any $y$. The recurrence equation is verified for any $y$ as well as my solution for $f(x)$ is also verified for any $x > 0$. I don't understand your objections to my answer.

Comment: @Cesareo Please don't get me wrong, it's never a personal thing. I'm just interested in the argument. My suspicion comes from the observation that e.g. $$(G(\pi),G(2\pi),G(4\pi),\ldots)=(1,2,-3,1,2,-3,\ldots)$$ and $$(G(e),G(2e),G(4e),\ldots)=(4,2,-6,4,2,-6,\ldots)$$ are compatible with the equation $G(4y)+G(2y)+G(y)=0$. We can extract $C_1,C_2$'s from both sequences, but they should always be equal?

Comment: @Song  The constant $C'_1,C'_2$ are free parameters. The recurrence equation is second order so it has two general parameters to fix depending on the boundary conditions. I included as a NOTE, a MATHEMATICA script to show this. Depending on the value $\pi$ or $e$ the condition to pass for $y=\pi, G(y) = 1$ or $y=e,G(y)=4$ could require different  $C'_1,C'_2$ of course. The behavior is much similar to the second order linear differential equations

Comment: @Cesareo You are wrong. Please read over my example and verify that it is (1) a solution to the recurrence, (2) not covered by your family of solutions.

Comment: Of course your family of solutions satisfies the recurrence. It is easy to verify. But there is an infinite dimensional space of other solutions.

Comment: I have explained and given a specific counterexample to the claim that your solution covers all solutions. Please check it carefully and if you don't get it then I'd be happy to discuss further.

Comment: @6005 The solution which obey $(y,G(y))$ should have the constants determined accordingly. Is the same procedure as with the second order linear differential equations: their solution(s) are in the form $C_1 \phi_1(x)+C_2\phi_2(x)$ any particular solution passing by $(y,G(y))$ should be tuned first with the constants $C_1,C_2$ So the solution which passes across $(2^k, G(2^k)), (2\cdot 2^k, G(2\dot 2^k))$ have different constants from the one passing across $(e, G(e)), (2e, G(2e))$. It is quite the same procedure as with linear DE's. It is a two parametric family of solutions.

Comment: @6005 My fault. I ignored the required condition that $f(x)$ should be increasing.

Comment: @Song My fault. I ignored the fact that $f(x)$  should be increasing.

Comment: Let me simplify the example: set $G(y) = 0$ if $y = 2^k$ for some integer $k$. Otherwise set $G(y) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi \log_2 y}{3} \right)$. This is a valid solution to the original equation which your family of solutions does not include.

Comment: I am sorry to say that your answer remains an incorrect proof as it assumes that the procedure for solving linear differential equations will apply here. That procedure does not apply. That procedure excludes many valid solutions such as the example I have just mentioned.